# Особенная пунктуация в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

[Размышляя, он одновременно разглядывал симпатичное, немного похожее на бамбук растение в горшке на подоконнике.] **Многим побывавшим в его кабинете растение очень нравилось, но лишь немногие знали, что это...**
[**Джон Болл. Пять осколков нефрита**](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=71213&p=41)

Не мудрствуя лукаво, я бы выделила оборот запятыми:
*Многим, **побывавшим в его кабинете,** растение очень нравилось...*

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять: **почему** такова пунктуация (без запятых)?

Answer (score 2):

[Не обособляются согласованные определения:](http://www.pandia.ru/text/78/392/51078.php)

Определения, относящиеся к неопределенным, определительным местоимениям, к слову «многие»:

*Тут есть **нечто** заслуживающее внимания.*

***Все*** пришедшие на митинг были настроены решительно.

***Многие*** побывавшие там разочарованы.

---

Те же примеры в другом [источнике](https://infourok.ru/material-punktuaciya-v-tablicah-2567968-page4.html).

---

И более [авторитетный сайт](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=140):

*Все отъезжающие и провожающие должны пройти в зал ожидания* (причастия имеют при себе определение — местоимение ***все***). — *Все, отъезжающие и провожающие, расположились в зале ожидания* (определения-причастия уточняют значение местоимения ***все***).

Answer (score 2):

Без запятых смысл такой: "многим из побывавших..." Запятые же (как и скобки) превращают оборот в уточнение (многим = всем побывавшим в его кабинете; нравится всем, кто видел, а их много).